# Can organizations be made temporarily invisible?

Tags: trello

Is it possible to make an organization invisible for periods of time and then make them visible at a later time when needed? We can make boards invisible without deleting them. Is there a way to do the same with an organization?

Answer (score 2):

You can make an organization public or private at any time. Just go to the organization profile, click 'Account', and change the visibility at the bottom of the page. You'll need to be an org admin to change the settings.